# Partitions of $n$ elements into $k$ subsets: formula and algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm seeking for the formula of the number and the algorithm (if any) for generation of all splits of $n$ numbers into $k$ subsets ($k < n$).

Example: let $n=5$, $k=3$. The numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$  can be divided into the following $3$ subsets:

- $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3, 4, 5\}$
- $\{1, 2\}, \{5\}, \{3, 4\}$
- $\{1, 5\}, \{2\}, \{3, 4\}$
- and so on...

The order does not matter: the subsets $\{3, 4\}$ and $\{4, 3\}$ are assumed to be equal as well as subsets in any series above can be permuted.

Comment: The number of partitions of an $n$ element set into $k$ nonempty subsets is $S(n,k)$, a *Stirling number of the second kind*.

Comment: Thanks, I already found it in Wikipedia. I suppose, that algorithms also exist.

Comment: "Very important"... why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but it seems like you're asking how to find [Stirling Partition Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).
I do not believe there is any known formulaic method to generate them, besides perhaps the relation S(n,r) = r(S(n-1),r)) + S(n-1,r-1), though that requires knowledge of S((n-1),r) and S(n-1,r-1).